# windows file extension associations

Tags: windows, file-association

I always thought that this was a reliable way to determine which program is used to open a file with a certain extension when you double click it in Windows Explorer.

```
C:\>assoc .txt
.txt=txtfile

C:\>ftype txtfile
txtfile=%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1
```

The above is my actual result. But it is UltraEdit that opens my text files.

Is this method not so reliable after all? Where can I see (and change), with a command or in the registry, which program opens my text files?

Comment: Check also `reg query "hkcr\.txt" /S` to see if there are `OpenWithList` or `OpenWithProgIDs` registered programs (and what is (default) ).

Comment: Command-line association and Explorer association may differ. Check `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.txt\UserChoice`.

Comment: `reg query HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.txt\OpenWithList`